# iOS Enterprise APNS expired

Tags: ios, ssl, apple-push-notifications, mdm

my Enterprise APNS for an App ID (MDM App) expired this week, unfortunately i did not notice it.
So i made a new request started create certificate for APNS within the APP ID and then finished request. I can see the new certificate under my App ID and APNS Distribution.
When I install my App i still get a Message "App cannot be laoded" - "App cannot be installed at the moment".
Although when i enroll device it's still the same. I know there was a problem when the distribution certificate or the Public APNS certificate expires you will have to re-enroll all device.

Comment: APNS has nothing to do with app installation, but what is your question here that you are asking i did not get that, can you tell more?

Comment: I have changed my APNS certificate and now i can't install my APP and like you said actually APNS has nothing to do with installation.

Comment: APNS is what triggers the device checking into your MDM for pending commands however; so if you mess it up you won't be able to install, update, remove, or push configuration changes to MDM applications.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to "renew" your existing APNS certificate, not issue an entirely new one. Otherwise you will have to re-enroll your MDM devices under the new APNS topic.